# What does it mean for a function to be differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What does it mean for the derivative of a function to exist at every point on the function's domain? It seems a very abstract thing to visualize.

Can someone elaborate?
 Answers are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the definition or for an explanation to it?

Comment: If you just want to visualize, it means the function is "smooth" (not the properly defined mathematical term smooth, just smooth as in nice), it has no corners or sharp points in it. The absolute value, $|x|$, isn't differentiable in $0$ because it's pointy there.

Comment: Roughly speaking, if you magnify the function that is differentiable on an interval at a point, it'll look like a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to visualize it in terms of the definition and secant lines.  Remember that the definition of the derivative at a point $x_{0}$ is

$$f'(x_{0}) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+h) - f(x_{0})}{h}.$$

For any fixed value of $h$, the line $$y = \frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}\left(x - x_{0}\right) + f(x_{0})$$ is the secant line through the points $(x_{0},f(x_{0}))$ and $(x_{0}+h,f(x_{0}+h))$.  If the derivative of $f$ exists at $x_{0}$ then regardless of your choice of $h$, as you take it to $0$ the secant lines will all approach the same tangent line, namely $$y = f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0}) + f(x_{0}).$$

One way to actually visualize it is with Desmos.  Take a look at [this example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ndvxd4nexi).  I included two functions (in red), one that is differentiable at zero and one that is not.  Click on the folder icons to switch them on/off.  As you move the slider for $h$ toward $0$ from the left and right observe the difference in the behavior of the secant line (in blue).  In the differentiable function the line approaches a horizontal line regardless of whether you approach $h=0$ from the left or the right. With the non-differentiable function, the secant line approaches a vertical line as $h\to 0$ from the right and a horizontal line as $h\to 0$ from the left.  A function which is differentiable everywhere will exhibit this sort of consistent behavior with respect to the secant lines at every point in its domain.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, saying the derivative of a function $f$ exists at a point $x$ in its domain means that, if you zoom in 'enough', it will look more and more like a straight line. The tangent line of $f$ at $x$, then, is that line it resembles if you zoom in, with the slope of the tangent line being the derivative at $x$.
If a function $f$ is differentiable at its entire domain, that simply means that you can zoom into each point, and it will resemble a straight line at each one (though, obviously, it can resemble a different line at each point - the derivative need not be constant).

Not every function has this nice property, for instance $f(x) = |x|$; no matter how much you zoom in at the point $x = 0$, it will never resemble a line. (For all other $x$, of course, it is differentiable).

Depending on how advanced a course may be, this idea can be developed further, in that one can speak of a function not just resembling a line 'around' a given point $x$, but it may resemble a parabola, or a cubic equation, or an even higher order polynomial (this is what Taylor's theorem is about, intuitively speaking).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was wondering what could be an example of a differentiable function which would resemble a higher degree polynomial when zoomed in? To my understanding, regardless of the degree of a polynomial, you can find a tangent line for the polynomial at any point. That tangent line is what the polynomial will resemble when zoomed in. So, any differentiable function resembles a straight line when sufficiently zoomed in and nothing else

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov In hindsight, I should've elaborated on that last paragraph. You're exactly right, any higher-degree polynomial is differentiable, so it will locally look like a line. The content of Taylor's theorem can be understood as giving you an even better approximation than just a line. Roughly speaking, to make something look like a line, you need to zoom in a whole lot. Approximating a function by the first few terms of its Taylor series gives you an approximation for which you need to 'zoom in less' for it to still look reasonable.

Comment: True, indeed. I appreciate your follow-up!

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov There are some [pictures and animations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) on Wikipedia that illustrate my point better than my words do.

Answer (score 0):

I think of "differentiable" as "smooth."  A differentiable function on the domain $(a,b)$ has no holes, points, cusps, vertical asymptotes or other things that might make the ride from $a$ to $b$ unpleasant.  The tangent line at every point is a really good approximation to the function, so "smooth" is a good word.

However, "smooth" is a technical term, so what I just wrote will eventually be misleading.  In higher math, a "smooth" function has to have a *continuous* derivative (or even several higher-order, continuous derivatives.)  But still, in layman's terms, "smooth" is a good way to think of "differentiable."